# How to resolve access denied error for user "root@localhost"

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to resolve access denied error for user "root@localhost" password "No" while inserting value in information_schema database.

I have granted All privileges to the root user. But I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

that does not sound like a good idea, in the first place. You're giving root privileges to anyone who stumbles across your web ui.

I'd suggest creating a new user (or users) with privileges to do only what they need to.

If you -must- do something as root through the ui, then for your own safety set a strong password!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're trying to do what you actually want to do. As in, the actual steps you're trying to take won't accomplish the action you desire.

You're not supposed to be able to directly INSERT to `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. From [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-schema.html):

> The INFORMATION_SCHEMA database contains several read-only tables. They are actually views, not base tables, so there are no files associated with them, and you cannot set triggers on them. Also, there is no database directory with that name.
>
> Although you can select INFORMATION_SCHEMA as the default database with a USE statement, **you can only read the contents of tables, not perform INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE operations on them.**

Now about your phpMyAdmin problem. Are you able to log in at the command line client? When you say you've granted all privileges to user root, from where have you done that? Also, didn't your MySQL come with a root user already created that has all privileges? I'm not sure why you would have to do the grants yourself. Show us your `config.inc.php` file, please.

Comment: Yes my MySQL has a root user already created with all privileges, actually I need to insert in the ROUTINES table (view) of INFORMATION_SCHEMA database. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to create a routine? There are other means provided to do that than directly manipulating INFORMATION_SCHEMA (phpMyAdmin's Routines tab at database level or the CREATE PROCEDURE SQL statement).

Comment: Yes, I want to create routines. There are previous entries in that ROUTINES tab from the project I'm working in. Now I want to do the same. Can you please tell me the way in which I can make it done?

Comment: The way to create a routine is generally using either phpMyAdmin's Routines tab at database level or the CREATE PROCEDURE SQL statement. See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html for more information about the syntax.